# Como puedo pasar el array $data a mi otra funcion ReporteExcel?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo esta clase que almacena dos funciones necesito enviar los datos almacenado en data a mi otra funcion para poder hacer un excel. Me gustaria conocer mas de este tema ya que en multiples ocasiones me paso de querer hacer un excel con datos de otro lado.

```
  class SplitMergeDocumentosController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

                                $data = [
                                    'id_corte' => $id_corte,
                                    'correctos' => $filecountCorrect,
                                    'incorrectos' =>  $filecountIncorrect,
                                    'total' => $filecountCorrect + $filecountIncorrect,
                                 ];

                                 if (isset($fileElimina)) {
                                    unlink($procesoFile.'document.pdf');
                                 }

                                return $data;
         
    } 


    public function ReporteExcel()
    {
            dd( $this->store());
            $date =date("m-d-Y", time());
            $hour =date("h:i:s a", time());
            $export = new ReporteExport([
                ['Fecha', 'hora' ,'correctos', 'incorrectos', 'total'],
                [ $date,  $hour , 'correctos', 'incorrectos', 'total'],
            ]);


            return Excel::download(  $export ,'Excel.xlsx');
}}
```

Comment: Tengo entendido que en Laravel se usa `dd($this->store());` para mostrar el contenido de los datos; en todo caso, asigna una variable, algo como `$data = $this->store();`

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Tu código es casi correcto, dd significa "Dump and die" es decir, muestra todo el contenido de la variable o funcion dentro del dd() y luego termina el programa

Crea una variable dentro de tu segunda función y con eso funcionará

```
   class SplitMergeDocumentosController extends Controller
   {
       public function store(Request $request)
       {
           $data = [
               'id_corte' => $id_corte,
               'correctos' => $filecountCorrect,
               'incorrectos' =>  $filecountIncorrect,
               'total' => $filecountCorrect + $filecountIncorrect,
               ];

           if (isset($fileElimina)) {
               unlink($procesoFile.'document.pdf');
           }

           return $data;
     
       }

       public function ReporteExcel()
       {
           $data = $this->store(); // $data es local en ReporteExcel
           $date =date("m-d-Y", time());
           $hour =date("h:i:s a", time());
           $export = new ReporteExport([
               ['Fecha', 'hora' ,'correctos', 'incorrectos', 'total'],
               [ $date,  $hour , 'correctos', 'incorrectos', 'total'],
               ]);


           return Excel::download(  $export ,'Excel.xlsx');
       }
   }
```

Otra forma sería crear una variable "global" dentro de tu clase, esta podrá ser utilizada en todas las funciones de tu clase

```
   class SplitMergeDocumentosController extends Controller
   {
       private $data = [];

       public function store(Request $request)
       {
           $this->data = [
               'id_corte' => $id_corte,
               'correctos' => $filecountCorrect,
               'incorrectos' =>  $filecountIncorrect,
               'total' => $filecountCorrect + $filecountIncorrect,
               ];

           if (isset($fileElimina)) {
               unlink($procesoFile.'document.pdf');
           }

           return true; //Ya no necesitas regresar data porque es global
     
       }

       public function ReporteExcel()
       {
           $this->data;// Aquí podrías utilizar el contenido de data, ten en cuenta que si la función store no se ha ejecutado entonces data será un arreglo vacío
           $date =date("m-d-Y", time());
           $hour =date("h:i:s a", time());
           $export = new ReporteExport([
               ['Fecha', 'hora' ,'correctos', 'incorrectos', 'total'],
               [ $date,  $hour , 'correctos', 'incorrectos', 'total'],
               ]);


           return Excel::download(  $export ,'Excel.xlsx');
       }
   }
```